# Spring data Page.getTotalElements is incorrect on the last page

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

On the last page, [PageImpl.getTotalElements](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageImpl.html#getTotalElements--) doesn't return the correct total number of elements.

For example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;

public class TestCaseGetTotalElements {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);

        Page<Integer> firstpage = new PageImpl<>(l, new PageRequest(0, 2), l.size());
        Page<Integer> secondpage = new PageImpl<>(l, new PageRequest(1, 2), l.size());

        System.out.println("On First page, total is " + firstpage.getTotalElements()); 
        System.out.println("On Second page, total is "+ secondpage.getTotalElements());
    }
}
```

will output:

```
On First page, total is 3
On Second page, total is 5
```

Is this a bug ?
If not, how to get the correct total number of elements ?

I'm using `spring-boot` 1.5.4, which depends on `spring-data-commons` 1.13.4.

Comment: None of the examples really makes sense. You're constructing a page which is supposed to have 2 elements, but pass a list of 3 elements as content of the page Since the size of the first page is 2 and the size of the second is effectively 3, the computed total is 5. Pass `l.subList(0, 2)` for the first page, and `l.subList(2, l.size())`, and you'll have a correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does print correct number of elements.

In second call you are feeding PageImpl with 3 values,  page 1 and size 2.

```
So total elements = page 0(2) + (page 1(2) + 1) 
page 1(2) + 1 -- > 3 values 


/**
 * Constructor of {@code PageImpl}.
 * 
 * @param content the content of this page, must not be {@literal null}.
 * @param pageable the paging information, can be {@literal null}.
 * @param total the total amount of items available. The total might be adapted considering the length of the content
 *          given, if it is going to be the content of the last page. This is in place to mitigate inconsistencies
 */
public PageImpl(List<T> content, Pageable pageable, long total) {

    super(content, pageable);

    this.pageable = pageable;
    this.total = pageable.toOptional().filter(it -> !content.isEmpty())//
            .filter(it -> it.getOffset() + it.getPageSize() > total)//
            .map(it -> it.getOffset() + content.size())//
            .orElse(total);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I should have read the javadoc of the constructor more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

this was the solution for the same error in my case

```
int pageSize = pageable.getPageSize();
long pageOffset = pageable.getOffset();
long total = pageOffset + list.size() + (list.size() == pageSize ? pageSize : 0);
Page<listType> page = new PageImpl<listType>(list, pageable,total)
```